# malloc error while reading a file in with pandas

Tags: python, macos, memory

I am getting the following error while reading a file into python using pandas.

```
**malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=8388608) failed (error code=3)**
***** error: can't allocate region securely
*** set a break point in malloc_error_break to debug**
```

I checked the activity monitor and I could see physical memory is available. I checked other related questions where the word '**securely**' is not part of the error message. I reckon there is a permission related issue I might not be aware of.
I ran the same script in an earlier version of MacOSX and I did not get any such issues.
Any help please?

Adding memory summary from crash report which suggests I still have some memory left:

[image: screenshot of memory summary from crash report]

UPDATE: Issue was resolved when running the script through Jupyter Notebook using ANACONDA distribution. The issue was only when I used the terminal

Comment: How big is the file? It sounds like it's just too big to load it all into memory.

Comment: @Barmar The file is about 500mb. The same script ran properly in an older version of mac. My machine was updated a couple of days ago and I am facing this error. I still have 3 to 4 gigs of memory left when I get the error